# How to avoid NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

The following line of code:

```cs
double? paidAmount = invoices.Value.Where(x => x.Status.Equals(Constants.InvoicePaid)).Sum(x => x.TotalAmount);
```

Is causing an error when the status is null.:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Can I avoid this exception using null-coalescing? If interested, here I'm checking if the status property is equal to `"paid"` I want to sum.

Comment: We need more information. Which property exactly is throwing the exception ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) On another note, `Can I avoid this exception using null-coalescing?`  have you tried it, what was the results?

Comment: Another option, do you have a choice of `Constants.InvoiceNotPaid` or maybe `Constants.InvoiceNew`, it would be helpful as it could be the default for `Status`... unless `null` is a valid value for notpaid/unknown etc...

Comment: @Fabjan the Status property is causing the exception

Answer (score 0):

You can use the null coalescing operator:

```cs
double? paidAmount = invoices.Value.Where(x => x.Status?.Equals(Constants.InvoicePaid)).Sum(x => x.TotalAmount);
```

This will evaluate to false if the `Status` is null.

Comment: `x` shouldn't ever be null, so I don't think you need that conditional operator there.

Comment: Noted, I've updated.

Comment: @ekke it doesn't work it cause compiler error: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type  because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type